# Find all the 4 digit vampire numbers

Tags: algorithm

I am solving a problem to find out all the 4 digit Vampire numbers.

A **Vampire Number** v=x*y is defined as a number with 'n' even number of digits formed by multiplying a pair of 'n/2'-digit numbers (where the digits are taken from the original number in any order)x and y together. If v  is a vampire number, then x&y and  are called its "fangs."

Examples of vampire numbers are:

```
    1.    1260=21*60
    2.    1395=15*93
    3.    1530=30*51
```

I have tried the brute force algorithm to combine different digits of a given number and multiply them together . But this method is highly inefficient and takes up a lot of time.

Is there a more efficient algorithmic solution to this problem?

Comment: This reminds me of the old days when we tried to solve these kinds of questions in ACM ICPC....

Comment: Can't you just iterate through all 9000 posibilities? That's not that much? Just start with `1000` which means `10 * 00`, check if the result is a vampire.

Comment: Or, alternatively, just a nested loop over the potential factors - multiply them and test the result... At least for 2-digit -> 4-digit case. Now, if you wanted to find all the 128-digit -> 256-digit cases, that's a completely different scale of problem...

Comment: @owlstead - There are more than 9000 possibilities, since you need to suss out the "fangs".  But there are no doubt ways to whittle down the candidates to a small number, so probably no more than maybe 200,000 possibilities.

Comment: @twalberg - Yep, that would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @HotLicks No matter how you slice it, for the 2-digit factor case, there are less than 100*100=10000 possibilities...

Comment: @twalberg -- Yeah -- should be able to knock the code out in 5 minutes and have it run in another 2-3.

Comment: Quick google ->`1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880` are all 4 digit vampire numbers. I'll create a script just for fun though

Comment: Have you seen http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl522332/math/vampires/ ?

Comment: Jup, calculated this, 7 distinct ones (I got forteen, but that's not with distinct x and y values). That was fun :). Oh, and it worked on the first run :P

Comment: @poorvankbhatia, maybe you should post your code as it's quite likely that your code has a bug or serious inefficiency. A quick python script I wrote solved this problem in about a second for the 4 digit case.

Comment: this is ridiculous.  the reason given for closure is intended for people asking for problems with code (things like syntax).  not for questions about algorithms.  "brute force algorithm" alone is enough to explain the issue (and motivate the excellent answer).  there is absolutely no need for an interesting question and brilliant answer like this to be closed - it's just small-minded rule following rather than trying to make the site a great place.  barmar, ziyao wei, woodchips, christoffer hammarström and marko should be ashamed of themselves.  really poor behaviour.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Or you can use a property of vampire numbers described on [this page](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl522332/math/vampires/) (linked from Wikipedia) :

> An important theoretical result found by Pete Hartley:
>
> ```
>       If x·y is a vampire number then x·y == x+y (mod 9)
> ```
>
> Proof: Let mod be the binary modulo operator and d(x) the sum of the decimal
>   digits of x. It is well-known that d(x) mod 9 = x mod 9, for all x.
>   Assume x·y is a vampire. Then it contains the same digits as x and y,
>   and in particular d(x·y) = d(x)+d(y). This leads to:
>             (x·y) mod 9 = d(x·y) mod 9 = (d(x)+d(y)) mod 9 = (d(x) mod 9 + d(y) mod 9) mod 9
>               = (x mod 9 + y mod 9) mod 9 = (x+y) mod 9
>
> The solutions to the [congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) are (x mod 9, y mod 9) in {(0,0),
>   (2,2), (3,6), (5,8), (6,3), (8,5)}

So your code could look like this :

```c
for(int i=18; i<100; i=i+9){          // 18 is the first multiple of 9 greater than 10
   for(int j=i; j<100; j=j+9){        // Start at i because as @sh1 said it's useless to check both x*y and y*x
       checkVampire(i,j);
   }
}

for(int i=11; i<100; i=i+9){          // 11 is the first number greater than 10 which is = 2 mod 9
   for(int j=i; j<100; j=j+9){
       checkVampire(i,j);
   }
}

for(int i=12; i<100; i=i+9){
   for(int j=i+3; j<100; j=j+9){
       checkVampire(i,j);
   }
}

for(int i=14; i<100; i=i+9){
   for(int j=i+3; j<100; j=j+9){
       checkVampire(i,j);
   }
}

// We don't do the last 2 loops, again for symmetry reasons
```

Since they are 40 elements in each of the sets like `{(x mod 9, y mod 9) = (0,0); 10 <= x <= y <= 100}`, you only do `4*40 = 160` iterations, when a brute-force gives you 10ˆ4 iterations. You can do even less operations if you take into account the `>= 1000` constraint, for instance you can avoid checking if `j < 1000/i`.

Now you can easily scale up to find vampires with more than 4 digits =)

Comment: Edited to avoid the (6,3) and (8,5) loops, which give the same numbers as (3,6) and (5,8)

Comment: I was considering suggesting a fast-out in my answer (something like `x*y%9 != (x*100+y)%9`) but I realised it was unrefined and that it was going to look stupid if somebody posted something properly thought-out like this.

Comment: @SamuelPeter yeah, ok, as it can be made to scale over larger amount of digits I'll agree with you and vote up (otherwise it *would* be too specific... )

Comment: The last couple of loops miss a few vampire numbers (such as 1395=15*93). Starting those loops at j=15 and j=17 gets me [1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880], which I believe are all the 4-digit vampire numbers.

Answer (score 10):

Iterate over all possible fangs (100 x 100 = 10000 possibilities), and find if their product has the same digits as the fangs.

Comment: I'm waiting for @twalberg to post that as an answer so I can credit it.

Comment: This seems like the most efficient way to do it. You can skip the 1-digit numbers, so it's only starting with (10*10), then (10*11), ... (11*11), (11*12) ... (99*99). You only end up doing 4,095 iterations.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another brute force (C) version, with a free bubble sort to boot...

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void bubsort(int *p)
{ while (1)
  { int s = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      if (p[i] > p[i + 1])
      { s = 1;
        int t = p[i]; p[i] = p[i + 1]; p[i + 1] = t;
      }

    if (!s) break;
  }
}

int main()
{ for (int i = 10; i < 100; ++i)
    for (int j = i; j < 100; ++j)
    { int p = i * j;

      if (p < 1000) continue;

      int xd[4];
      xd[0] = i % 10;
      xd[1] = i / 10;
      xd[2] = j % 10;
      xd[3] = j / 10;

      bubsort(xd);
      int x = xd[0] + xd[1] * 10 + xd[2] * 100 + xd[3] * 1000;

      int yd[4];
      yd[0] = p % 10;
      yd[1] = (p / 10) % 10;
      yd[2] = (p / 100) % 10;
      yd[3] = (p / 1000);

      bubsort(yd);
      int y = yd[0] + yd[1] * 10 + yd[2] * 100 + yd[3] * 1000;

      if (x == y)
        printf("%2d * %2d = %4d\n", i, j, p);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Runs pretty much instantaneously. Variable names aren't too descriptive, but should be pretty obvious...

The basic idea is to start with two potential fangs, break them down into digits, and sort the digits for easy comparison. Then we do the same with the product - break it down to digits and sort. Then we re-constitute two integers from the sorted digits, and if they're equal, we have a match.

Possible improvements: 1) start `j` at `1000 / i` instead of `i` to avoid having to do `if (p < 1000) ...`, 2) maybe use insertion sort instead of bubble sort (but who's gonna notice those 2 extra swaps?), 3) use a real `swap()` implementation, 4) compare the arrays directly rather than building a synthetic integer out of them. Not sure any of those would make any measurable difference, though, unless you run it on a Commodore 64 or something...

Edit: Just out of curiosity, I took this version and generalized it a bit more to work for the 4, 6 and 8 digit cases - without any major optimization, it can find all the 8-digit vampire numbers in < 10 seconds...

Answer (score 3):

This is an ugly hack (brute force, manual checking for permutations, unsafe buffer operations, produces dupes, etc.) but it does the job. Your new exercise is to improve it :P

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_number) that there are 7 vampire numbers which are 4 digits long. The [full code has found them all](http://ideone.com/kvz9MZ), even some duplicates.

**Edit:** [Here's a slightly better comparator function.](http://ideone.com/2kzoIs)

**Edit 2:** [Here's a C++ version](http://ideone.com/hZrz5A) that uniques results (therefore it avoids duplicates) using an `std::map` (and stores the last occurrence of the particular vampire number along with its factors in it). It also meets the criterion that at least one of the factors should not end with `0`, i. e. a number is not a vampire number if both of the multiplicands are divisible by then. This test looks for 6-digit vampire numbers and it does indeed find exactly 148 of them, in accordance with what Wikipedia sates.

---

The original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getdigits(char buf[], int n)
{
    while (n) {
        *buf++ = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
}

int is_vampire(const char n[4], const char i[2], const char j[2])
{
    /* maybe a bit faster if unrolled manually */
    if (i[0] == n[0]
     && i[1] == n[1]
     && j[0] == n[2]
     && j[1] == n[3])
        return 1;

    if (i[0] == n[1]
     && i[1] == n[0]
     && j[0] == n[2]
     && j[1] == n[3])
            return 1;

    if (i[0] == n[0]
     && i[1] == n[1]
     && j[0] == n[3]
     && j[1] == n[2])
            return 1;

    if (i[0] == n[1]
     && i[1] == n[0]
     && j[0] == n[3]
     && j[1] == n[2])
            return 1;

    // et cetera, the following 20 repetitions are redacted for clarity
    // (this really should be a loop, shouldn't it?)

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
            int n = i * j;
            if (n < 1000)
                continue;

            char ndigits[4];
            getdigits(ndigits, n);

            char idigits[2];
            char jdigits[2];
            getdigits(idigits, i);
            getdigits(jdigits, j);

            if (is_vampire(ndigits, idigits, jdigits))
                printf("%d * %d = %d\n", i, j, n);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you can just [change j to start from i](http://ideone.com/h92Fx4) to avoid the need for the map.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have given up so easily on brute force.  You have distinct set of numbers, 1000 to 9999 that you must run through.  I would divide up the set into some number of subsets, and then spin up threads to handle each subset.

You could further divide the work be coming up with the various combinations of each number; IIRC my discrete math, you have 4*3*2 or 24 combinations for each number to try.

A producer / consumer approach might be worthwhile.

Comment: Actually, at most 24 combinations for each numbers, if any number appears more than twice, you can remove duplicates, like "2222" can only be "22" and "22". To reduce duplicates, we can sort x and y since the order doesn't change the result of a multiplication and it will make easy to not calculate 23 x 24 and 24 x 23. There are probably ways to optimize more but I'd do it like that probably.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix that reminds me about the Sudoku solver I once made (without looking up pre-made solutions, of course). I added a whole range of smart tricks to make it faster, only to find out it took 0.3 seconds instead of 0.2 seconds (which was basically the startup of the VM). Of course, you need more rules to slay bigger vampires :P

Comment: Ahah sure, tests that actually take more time to do than the actual operation) But that's tricky and really system dependent sometimes

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: full brute force that weeds out identical X and Y values...

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Vampire {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 10; x < 100; x++) {
            String sx = String.valueOf(x);
            for (int y = x; y < 100; y++) {
                int v = x * y;
                String sy = String.valueOf(y);
                String sv = String.valueOf(v);
                if (sortVampire(sx + sy).equals(sortVampire(sv))) {
                    System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", x, y, v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Character> sortVampire(String v) {
        List<Character> vc = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int j = 0; j < v.length(); j++) {
            vc.add(v.charAt(j));
        }
        Collections.sort(vc);
        return vc;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't find, for example, `1260`, which is `21*60`.

Comment: @JimMischel: Output: 60 * 21 = 1260 - why do you think it is faulty?

Comment: Now I see. Interesting algorithm.

Comment: Actually since x and y are < 100, v is always <10000. You could do instead if(v<1000){break;} ;)

Comment: @SamuelPeter oh, yeah, brain is a bit wobbly at this time of night :P

Answer (score 1):

Iteration seems fine to me, since you only need to do this once to find all the values and you can just cache them afterwards. Python (3) version that takes about 1.5 seconds:

```py
# just some setup
from itertools import product, permutations
dtoi = lambda *digits: int(''.join(str(digit) for digit in digits))
gen = ((dtoi(*digits), digits) for digits in product(range(10), repeat=4) if digits[0] != 0)
l = []

for val, digits in gen:
    for check1, check2 in ((dtoi(*order[:2]), dtoi(*order[2:])) for order in permutations(digits) if order[0] > 0 and order[2] > 0):
        if check1 * check2 == val:
            l.append(val)
            break

print(l)
```

Which will give you `[1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880]`

Comment: Yeah, but can you do it with a recursive algorithm?

Comment: If the language is not given as a tag it often pays to add `<!-- language: lang-py -->` to get syntax highlighting...

Comment: @HotLicks Sure you can do it with a recursive algorithm (iterative and recursive algorithms can be mapped to each other similar to how deterministic and non-deterministic finite automata can), but Python isn't well suited to that.

Comment: @owlstead Interesting, I was not aware of that. I guess the language-guessing algorithm the syntax highlighter uses needs some help sometimes.

Comment: @JAB - Making it that much more challenging!  Code it as a tree search.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't see any real point in coding the vampire number determination as a tree search. Finding the closest vampire number to a given value with the calculated set of numbers would be fairly easy to implement as a binary tree search, however. `check(node) -> ((val < node.val) -> (node.lchild !=null ? check(node.lchild) : node.val); (val > node.val) -> (node.rchild !=null ? check(node.rchild) : node.val); (val == node.val) -> node.val)` or something like that.

Comment: @JAB - I'm just jabbing you.  Since this is a "toy" problem anyway, it's interesting to speculate over some of the weirdest possible ways to solve it.

Comment: @HotLicks Okay, how about this, then? Generate a random integer using C's `rand()`, adding it to a very large array of values if it is not already present in the array; then check if it satisfies the conditions for a vampire number, and if so add it to the result list. When the number of values stored in the array reaches `RAND_MAX+1` (range of `rand()` is 0 to `RAND_MAX`), print the result list. (Note that this algorithm checks values even if they had already been checked and does not account for duplicates in the result list.)

Comment: @JAB - Sometimes the distinction between "weird" and "stupid" is subtle. ;)

Comment: @HotLicks I'd say they cover different aspects, so "weird" and "stupid" don't necessarily have to be disjunct.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force version in C# with LINQ:

```csharp
class VampireNumbers
{
    static IEnumerable<int> numberToDigits(int number)
    {
        while(number > 0)
        {
            yield return number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
    }

    static bool isVampire(int first, int second, int result)
    {
        var resultDigits = numberToDigits(result).OrderBy(x => x);

        var vampireDigits = numberToDigits(first)
                             .Concat(numberToDigits(second))
                             .OrderBy(x => x);                                  

        return resultDigits.SequenceEqual(vampireDigits);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vampires = from fang1 in Enumerable.Range(10, 89)
                       from fang2 in Enumerable.Range(10, 89)
                       where fang1 < fang2
                             && isVampire(fang1, fang2, fang1 * fang2)       
                       select new { fang1, fang2 };

        foreach(var vampire in vampires)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(vampire.fang1 * vampire.fang2 
                              + " = " 
                              + vampire.fang1 
                              + " * " 
                              + vampire.fang2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `resultDigits = result.ToString().OrderBy(c => c)` and `vampireDigits = (first.ToString() + second.ToString()).OrderBy(c => c)`. Then `return resultDigits.SequenceEqual(vampireDigits)`.

Comment: Nice! That checks out on my system, and it was quite quick. It flew when I set the ranges to (10,999) instead of (10,89). It only started crawling noticeably when I set the ranges to (10,9999) and it got to two four-digit numbers. Respectable! It took a few minutes.

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks for that, changed to use SequenceEqual. I still like using integer arithmetic a bit better than using strings though.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to someone mentioned above, my method is to first find all permutations of a number, then split them in half to form two 2-digit numbers, and test if their product equal to the original number.

Another interesting discussion above is how many permutations a number can have. Here is my opinion:
(1) a number whose four digitals are the same has 1 permutation;
(2) a number who has only two different digits has 6 permutations (it doesn't matter if it contains zeros, because we don't care after permutation if it is still a 4-digit number);
(3) a number who has three different digits has 12 permutations;
(4) a number with all four different digits has 24 permutations.

```
public class VampireNumber {

// method to find all permutations of a 4-digit number
public static void permuta(String x, String s, int v)
{for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{permuta( x + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0,i) + s.substring(i+1), v);
if (s.length() == 1)
    {x = x + s;
    int leftpart = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0,2));
    int rightpart = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(2));
    if (leftpart*rightpart == v) 
        {System.out.println("Vampir = " + v);
        }
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {
permuta("", Integer.toString(i), i); //convert the integer to a string
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would try would be to loop through each number in [1000, 9999], and test if any permutation of its digits (split in the middle) multiplied to make it.

This will require (9999 - 1000) * 24 = 215,976 tests, which should execute acceptably fast on a modern machine.

I would definitely store the digits separately, so you can avoid having to do something like a bunch of division to extract the digits from a single integer.

If you write your code such that you're only ever doing integer addition and multiplication (and maybe the occasional division to carry), it should be pretty fast. You could further increase the speed by skipping two-digit pairs which "obviously" won't work - e.g., ones with leading zeros (note that the largest product than can be produced by a one digit number and a two digit number is 9 * 99, or 891).

Also note that this approach is embarassingly parallel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), so if you really need to speed it up even more then you should look into testing the numbers in separate threads.

Comment: True, but each test is more computationally complex, since you will need to do something like H2CO3's solution, where you do a bunch of modulo divisions to extract the digits and compare them. I would be curious to see which is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that to perform the fewest possible tests without relying on any particularly abstract insights, you probably want to iterate over the fangs and cull any obviously pointless candidates.

For example, since `x*y == y*x` about half your search space can be eliminated by only evaluating cases where `y > x`.  If the largest two-digit fang is 99 then the smallest which can make a four-digit number is 11, so don't start lower than 11.

EDIT:

OK, throwing everything I thought of into the mix (even though it looks silly against the leading solution).

```
for (x = 11; x < 100; x++)
{
    /* start y either at x, or if x is too small then 1000 / x */
    for (y = (x * x < 1000 ? 1000 / x : x); y < 100; y++)
    {
        int p = x * y;

        /* if sum of digits in product is != sum of digits in x+y, then skip */
        if ((p - (x + y)) % 9 != 0)
            continue;

        if (is_vampire(p, x, y))
            printf("%d\n", p);
    }
}
```

and the test, since I haven't seen anyone use a histogram, yet:

```
int is_vampire(int p, int x, int y)
{
    int h[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        h[p % 10]++;
        p /= 10;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        h[x % 10]--;
        h[y % 10]--;
        x /= 10;
        y /= 10;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (h[i] != 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i = 10; $i <= 99; $j++) {

    // Extract digits
    $digits = str_split($i);

    // Loop through 2nd number
    for ($j = 10; $j <= 99; $j++) {

         // Extract digits
         $j_digits = str_split($j);
         $digits[2] = $j_digits[0];
         $digits[3] = $j_digits[1];

         $product = $i * $j;

         $product_digits = str_split($product);

         // check if fangs

         $inc = 0;

         while (in_array($digits[$inc], $product_digits)) {

            // Remove digit from product table
               /// So AAAA -> doesnt match ABCD
             unset($product_digits[$array_serach($digits[$inc], $product_digits)]);

             $inc++;

             // If reached 4 -> vampire number
             if ($inc == 4) {

                  $vampire[] = $product;
                  break;
             }
         }
    }
}

// Print results
print_r($vampire);
?>
```

Took less than a second on PHP. couldn't even tell it had to run 8100 computations... computers are fast!

Results:

Gives you all the 4 digits plus some are repeated. You can further process the data and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

1260 1395 1435 1530 1827 2187 6880 is vampire

I am new to programming... But there are only 12 combinations in finding all 4-digit vampire numbers. My poor answer is:

```
public class VampNo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {

            int a = i/1000;
            int b = i/100%10;
            int c = i/10%10;
            int d = i%10;

                 if((a * 10 + b) * (c * 10 + d) == i || (b * 10 + a) * (d * 10 + c) == i ||
                    (a * 10 + d) * (b * 10 + c) == i || (d * 10 + a) * (c * 10 + b) == i ||
                    (a * 10 + c) * (b * 10 + d) == i || (c * 10 + a) * (d * 10 + b) == i ||
                    (a * 10 + b) * (d * 10 + c) == i || (b * 10 + a) * (c * 10 + d) == i ||
                    (b * 10 + c) * (d * 10 + a) == i || (c * 10 + b) * (a * 10 + d) == i ||
                    (a * 10 + c) * (d * 10 + b) == i || (c * 10 + a) * (b * 10 + d) == i)
                System.out.println(i + " is vampire");

        }
    }
}
```

The main task now is to simplify boolean expression in If() block

Answer (score 0):

I've edited Owlstead's algorithm a bit to make it more understandable to Java beginners/learners.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Vampire {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 10; x < 100; x++) {
        String sx = Integer.toString(x);
        for (int y = x; y < 100; y++) {
            int v = x * y;
            String sy = Integer.toString(y);
            String sv = Integer.toString(v);
            if( Arrays.equals(sortVampire(sx + sy), sortVampire(sv))) 
                System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d%n", x, y, v);
        }
    }
}
private static char[] sortVampire (String v){
    char[] sortedArray = v.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
    return sortedArray;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This python code run very fast (O(n2))

```js
result = []
for i in range(10,100):
    for j in range(10, 100):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        k = i * j
        if k < 1000 or k > 10000:
            continue
        else:
            for item in str(i):
                list1.append(item)
            for item in str(j):
                list1.append(item)
            for item in str(k):
                list2.append(item)
            flag = 1  
            for each in list1:
                if each not in list2:
                    flag = 0
                else:
                    list2.remove(each)
            for each in list2:
                if each not in list1:
                    flag = 0

            if flag == 1:
                if k not in result:
                    result.append(k)
for each in result:
    print(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is my code. To generate zombie numbers we need to use Random class :)

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

class VampireNumbers {
    static PrintStream p = System.out;

    private static Set<Integer> findVampireNumber() {
        Set<Integer> vampireSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int y = 1000; y <= 9999; y++) {
            char[] numbersSeparately = ("" + y).toCharArray();
            int numberOfDigits = numbersSeparately.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfDigits; j++) {
                    if (i != j) {
                        int value1 = Integer.valueOf("" + numbersSeparately[i] + numbersSeparately[j]);
                        int ki = -1;
                        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfDigits; k++) {
                            if (k != i && k != j) {
                                ki = k;
                            }
                        }
                        int kj = -1;
                        for (int t = 0; t < numberOfDigits; t++) {
                            if (t != i && t != j && t != ki) {
                                kj = t;
                            }
                        }

                        int value21 = Integer.valueOf("" + numbersSeparately[ki] + numbersSeparately[kj]);
                        int value22 = Integer.valueOf("" + numbersSeparately[kj] + numbersSeparately[ki]);
                        if (value1 * value21 == y && !(numbersSeparately[j] == 0 && numbersSeparately[kj] == 0)
                                || value1 * value22 == y
                                        && !(numbersSeparately[j] == 0 && numbersSeparately[ki] == 0)) {
                            vampireSet.add(y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return vampireSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> vampireSet = findVampireNumber();
        Iterator<Integer> i = vampireSet.iterator();
        int number = 1;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            p.println(number + ": " + i.next());
            number++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great answers! here's one that uses @rmmh's suggestions and implemented using python. I find his suggestion being fast for even the 6 digits vampire numbers.

```py
s=set()
for x in range(99):# change this to 999 for 4 and 6 digit
    for y in range(99):# change this to 999 for 4 and 6 digit
        s1,s2=str(x),str(y)
        if x%10+y%10 and len(s1)==len(s2) and sorted(s1+s2)==sorted(str(x*y)):
           s.add(x*y)
for i in sorted(s):
    print(i)
```